# Change table name/model name dynamically in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model

I have two tables that have the exact same columns. I wish to change the model name on the fly and pull out data from the one that the user has picked. How do achieve this? I have code as such :-

```
def display
    @active_model =  get_active_model(params[:active_model])
    versions = @active_model.group(:version).count
end
```

and get_active_model looks something like this :-

```
def get_active_model(model_param)
    case model_param
    when 'Eclipse'
        return "Eclipse"
    when 'Jdt'
        return "Jdt"
    end
end
```

The "@active_model" is the model chosen by the user and can be 'Eclipse' or 'JDT'. When I replace "@active_model" with the model name directly it works. But I want to change it dynamically. I'm fairly new to ROR, so please give me your suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use model name instead of string:

```
def get_active_model(model_param)
    case model_param
    when 'Eclipse'
        return Eclipse
    when 'Jdt'
        return JDT
    end
end
```